# How to save both parent and child in jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to make a register request that requires a `User` object that includes a `UserLogin` object containing username and password. But when I trying to save `User` object, it said `userid` (fk of `UserLogin` can't not be null).

[See this image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MFyQ.png)

And here is my EDR

[image]

Here is my config to map 2 objects
Class User

```
class User {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private UserLogin userLogin;
}

class UserLogin {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
}
```

My code to save them

```
@Transactional
public User register(User user) {
    Set<UserRole> roleSet = new HashSet<>();
    UserRole role = new UserRole();
    // default role
    role.setRole_name("ROLE_NHANVIEN");
    role.setId(4L);
    roleSet.add(role);
    // encrypt pass
    user.setRoles(roleSet);
    log.info(user.getUserLogin().getUsername());
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: is the UserLogin.user reference set? call user.getUserLogin().setUser(user) before the save if it isn't. The owning side needs to be set on bidirectional relationships for the foreign keys to be set

Comment: Thanks, it works, I thought that just add UserLogin to User and cascade do it all

Comment: Nope, JPA requires you manage your entity model by setting both sides of relationships, trying to make it behave close to what you would expect from a POJO.